# Oracle select rows from a query which are not exist in another query

Tags: oracle, join, plsql

Let me explain the question.

I have two tables, which have 3 columns with same data tpyes. The 3 columns create a key/ID if you like, but the name of the columns are different in the tables.
Now I am creating queries with these 3 columns for both tables. I've managed to independently get these results

For example:

```
SELECT ID, FirstColumn, sum(SecondColumn)
    FROM (SELECT ABC||DEF||GHI AS ID, FirstTable.* 
            FROM FirstTable
            WHERE ThirdColumn = *1st condition*)
GROUP BY ID, FirstColumn
;

SELECT ID, SomeColumn, sum(AnotherColumn)
    FROM (SELECT JKM||OPQ||RST AS ID, SecondTable.* 
            FROM SecondTable 
            WHERE AlsoSomeColumn  = *2nd condition*)
GROUP BY ID, SomeColumn
;
```

So I make a very similar queries for two different tables. I know the results have a certain number of same rows with the ID attribute, the one I've just created in the queries. I need to check which rows in the result are not in the other query's result and vice versa.

Do I have to make temporary tables or views from the queries? Maybe join the two tables in a specific way and only run one query on them?

As a beginner I don't have any experience how to use results as an input for the next query. I'm interested what is the cleanest, most elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you most probably don't need any "temporary" tables. WITH factoring clause would help.

Here's an example:

```
with 
first_query as
  (select id, first_column, ...
     from (select ABC||DEF||GHI as id, ...)
  ),
second_query as
  (select id, some_column, ...
     from (select JKM||OPQ||RST as id, ...)
  )
select id from first_query
minus
select id from second_query;
```

For another result you'd just switch the tables, e.g.

```
with ... <the same as above>
select id from second_query
minus
select id from first_query
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! One question: Is there no contradiction with the same 'id' column name using `with`? I mean shouldn't I gave the same alias for the selected attributes if I want to `minus` one from another? It seems I'll get an empty results otherwise.

Comment: You're welcome. In order to avoid possible contradiction, use table aliases **everywhere** and precede column names by those aliases, e.g. `select f.id from first_query f`

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. I've tried to use `select * from first_query natural join second_query` after the `with` block to see the rows which are the same for the `id` columns. Still, I get an empty row :/

Comment: IDs that are contained in both first_query and second_query would be `select id from first_query INTERSECT select id from second_query`